# Permissions error setting up SharePoint 2010 PowerShell account privileges

Tags: 2010, permissions, powershell, sharepoint-foundation, administration

SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Std SP1 (Domain Controller) in a simple farm with a single SQL Server 2008 SP1/Windows Server 2008 Std SP2 backend

I realise installing SP on a DC is not advised but I've no alternative.

Trying to run Get-SPWeb -site [site path] I get the following error:

> Get-SPWeb : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) At line:1 char:10 + Get-SPWeb <<<< -site [site path] + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share....SPCmdletGetWeb:SPCmdletGetWeb) [Get-SPWeb], Unauthorize dAccessException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetWeb

I am running as SP_admin. To make sure SP_admin has SharePoint_Shell_Access role on the database, I tried to run Add-SPShellAdmin -username DOMAIN\SP_admin -database [GUID] but then got this error:

> Add-SPShellAdmin : You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet. At line:1 char:17 + Add-SPShellAdmin <<<< -username DOMAIN\SP_admin -database $spcdb + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...AddSPShellAdmin:SPCmdletAddSPShellAdmin) [Add-SPShellAdm in], SPException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletAddSPShellAdmin

I have checked:

- I am running as SP_admin account
- SP_admin is member of Administrators group
- SP_admin is member of WSS_ADMIN_WPG group
- SP_admin has securityadmin role on the SQL Server instance
- SP_admin has db_owner role on content database

Why is it complaining I need to run as Machine administrator when the account is in the Administrators group? Could it be to do with it being a DC and AD replacing local groups?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx comments that "Typically, the person that will use the Add-SPShellAdmin cmdlet must be associated with the user account that was used for Setup." and in this case that is true.

Comment: One more thing, you could mark my reply as answer, if my post has helped you. read more about in FAQs sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I just runned the Sharepoint Power Shell as an admnistrator and it worked! Pd: I'm using Sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be allowed to execute PowerShell commands against a specific site collection, the user running the script needs certain access to both the database and every web front end in the farm. Even if you are a farm administrator and you have not been given Shell Admin Access, then you won’t be able to execute farm administrative operation using PowerShell. There are lots of operations that you cannot do via the Central Administration GUI and for which you will require Shell Admin Access.

Run this in the SharePoint PowerShell cmdlet

```
Add-SPShellAdmin -username testuser
```

[Follow Anders post for more information](http://sites.wizdim.com/andersrask/sharepoint/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sharepoint_shell_access-role-on-a-content-database/)

If you get errors like “You need to have machine administrator privileges to run this cmdlet”, **you need to run the shell as administrator or disable UAC on the server**.

If the PS script is launched from Task Scheduler, think of selecting the "Run with highest privileges" checkbox.

Comment: As I mention in my question, this is the command I have tried to run. I am using the SharePoint Management Shell. I am not using the farm admin account but the installation/setup admin account. If, in order to be able to run Add-SPAdmin, I need privileges additional to those I have listed, what are they?

Comment: Did you make sure that SP_admin is member of local machine administrators?

Comment: DCs don't have local groups as these are replaced by Active Directory groups. The account is a member of the Built-In Administrators group in AD.

Comment: You can use the SPShellAdmin cmdlets to help you manage these requirements. When you run the Add-SPShellAdmin cmdlet to add a userid to the SharePoint_Shell_Admin role, you must be mapped to Security_Admin role on the SQL instance and the db_owner role to the relevant databases. You need to run the Add-SPShellAdmin cmdlet for each content database that you want the userid to access.

Comment: Also, If you get errors like “You need to have machine administrator privileges to run this cmdlet”, you need to run the shell as administrator or disable UAC on the server.

Comment: As you mention @Free Style, the problem was UAC. I can't believe it was something so simple! I was logged in as domain\administrator and was using runas to open Management Shell in SP_admin user context. Logging in as SP_admin and then using Run As Administrator instead allowed me to run the cmdlet. It turns out, however, that the cmdlet will fail to add SP_admin to the SharePoint_Shell_Access role on the config database (of which it is the owner), so it seems you cannot use this cmdlet to give permission to the SP_admin account itself. I was able to use the cmdlet to grant permission to anoth

Comment: Great it helped you. Disabling UAC shouldn't be bothering you too much because you shouldn't be working directly on the server computer's desktop all that much for it to be an issue. You should be installing the admin. tools on a client computer, logging-on with a non-administrative account on that client computer for day-to-day work, and running the admin. tools with "Run As" and an administrative account.

Comment: One more thing, you could mark my reply as answer, if my post has helped you. read more about in FAQs http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

For your part about not having rights on certain databases, I found this at http://www.techques.com/question/19-12904/Error---Get-SPWeb-in-Powershell

> The account will need permissions on the content database. Just executing:
>
> ```
> Add-SPShellAdmin CONTOSO\User1
> ```
>
> Will give you access to the configuration database, but not the content database. Also provide access to the content database by giving access to the content database by using the -database parameter
>
> ```
> Add-SPShellAdmin -UserName CONTOSO\User1 -database 4251d855-3c15-4501-8dd1-98f960359fa6
> ```
>
> You can provide access to all content databases and SharePoint service application databases by using a command like:
>
> ```
> Get-SPDatabase | Add-SPShellAdmin CONTOSO\User1
> ```